# Element flow behind limits resposive overflow div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, resize, overflow

I have this code, I want the div `<div class="chat_container>` to resize and change the height of scroll so the elements inside never go behind, can you help me out ?

As you can figure out the `<li>` are disappear because of size of screen.

You can check the problem by resizing the fiddle.

```css
*{
 padding:0;
 margin: 0;
 border:0;
 overflow:hidden !important;
}

.navbar {
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #e67e22;
 z-index: 1000;
}

.friendlist {
 width: 15%;
 background-color: #eee;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 float: left;
}

.menu {
 background-color: yellow ;
 width: 85%;
 margin-left: 15%;
 height: 50px;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.chat_container{
 overflow-y: scroll !important;
 width: 85%;
 height: 69%;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 15%;
}

.texto {
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 15%;
 width: 85%;
 height: 12.1%;
 background-color: green;
 bottom: 50px;
}

footer {
 bottom: 0;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px ;
 background-color: #e67e22;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Maquete</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="navbar">
 </div>
 <div class="friendlist">
 </div>
 <div class="menu">
  Rafael<br>
  00:15
 </div>
 <div class="chat_container">
  <ol>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
   <li>ddsadsadassaddsa</li>
  </ol>
 </div>
 <div class="texto">
 </div>
 <footer>
  Interact
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly the cause of the problem is the mixed units px and % in height.

You can use calc to fix it.

Something like:

```
.chat_container{
    ...
    height: calc(85% - 50px);
    ...
}

.texto{
    ...
    height: calc(15% - 50px);
    ...
}
```